# App Store: launching for iPhone/iPod only, not iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

How do I launch my app only for iPhone/iPod, not for iPad on the App Store? I can't seem to find any setting neither in my .plist file nor in iTunesConnect. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably change _launch_ to _publish_ since your question can be easily misunderstood at the moment.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me. If you wanna make your app for iPhone/iTouch only, then go for Ladislav's answer. If you wanna see whether what device is when the app launched, then go for Richard J. Ross III's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check `Build Settings` and find key: `Targeted device family`

There you have `iPhone`, `iPad` or `iPhone/iPad` options to choose

When you build the app and send it to Apple, it just checks values there and makes it available for the device specified.

Comment: That doesn't prevent the app from being launched on iPad, though.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I'm only asking about app store, I'll rephrase to make that clearer.

Answer (score 10):

You can't.  Apple's App store guidelines appear to specifically not allow iPhone apps that don't run or that crash under (1X/2X) compatibility mode on an iPad.

Comment: +1. Your app will always run in (1x/2x) mode, even if they are iPhone specific.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but the answer could be useful to other developers:

- If you want your app to run on both iPhone and iPod I don't see the point to prevent it from running on an iPad under (1X/2X) compatibility mode. You may loose some consumers for nothing.
- If you want your app to run on iPhone only because you need some capabilities like telephony. The good way would be to use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and to set "sms" and "telephony". See Apple doc for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

One way I could see this working is like this:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     if (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
          return NO;

     // rest of launching code
     return YES;
}
```