# Launch an application available only for iPhone with Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I was reading the thread:
[App Store: launching for iPhone/iPod only, not iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056725/app-store-launching-for-iphone-ipod-only-not-ipad)
and checking those answers, to try changing the `Targeted Device Family`,
but my options are **1**; **2** and **1, 2** and not **iPhone**; **iPad**; **iPhone/iPad**.

[image: Targeted Device Family options]

How can I set this application available only for iPhones?

Comment: Please note that iPhone-only apps must also work as-is on an iPad. iPhone-only apps run on an iPad in a 3.5" iPhone compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **Targeted device family** to **1**, that corresponds to iPhone. This is a string localization bug in Xcode.

Comment: That's weird, I can't upload the version because my app is not totally compatible with `iPad`, and I uploaded with the only iPhone target device family